# Is there anything to make on_member_join in discord.py work?

Tags: discord.py

I'm currently programming a bot and my first goal is to make the bot welcome and say goodbye to members that join or leave, but the bot sends nothing, not even showing any error.

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(" System: A member has joined the server!")
    def sprint(str):
        for c in str + '\n':
            sys.stdout.write(c)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(3./90)
    sprint(" Bot: Oh hey, looks like "+member.name+" has joined..")
    
    #send message to a specific channel
    
    channel = client.get_channel(channel id from the welcome channel)
    await channel.send("Hey! Welcome to the server, "+member.mention+"! I hope you read the #rules before doing anything, otherwise have fun and enjoy your stay!")
```

I did it last time before I recreated the script, but the `on_member_join` thing doesn't work, not even `on_member_leave`! (I'm doing the `on_member_join` first to check if it's working)

My alternate account rejoined my server, but the bot (except MEE6) didn't send anything.. Is there anything you guys can help me?

Comment: do you have `intents.members` enabled?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I don't see ```intents.members``` anywhere in my script.. Where do I add that?

Here's the beginning of my codes:
```import os

import discord
import discord.ext
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 'token from my bot'

intents = discord.Intents(members=True)
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
 print(" System: Bot is ready!")```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to enable the member intent by creating an instance of `discord.Intents.default`, setting Intents.members to True, and passing the instance into your commands.Bot or discord.Client constructor, like:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(intents=intents)
```

You'll also need to enable the members intent in the Discord dev portal (https://discord.com/developers). Go to that url, click on your application, go to the Bot tab, scroll down to the 'privileged gateway intents' section, and enable the members intent.
Then, restart your bot, and member events should work.
(for more info, look at https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html)

Comment: It's still not working... I've already enabled "Server Members Intent", but the bot is still sending nothing..

Comment: Since you have instances of both discord.Client and commands.Bot (which you shouldn't do), and you've only registered the events for your Client instance, make sure you pass the intents to `client`, not `bot`.

Comment: I already have passed the intents to ```client```...

Comment: What does the beginning of your code look like? (where you define intents and your Client instance)

Comment: ```import os
import discord
import discord.ext

TOKEN = 'token from my bot'

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
 print(" System: Bot is ready!")```

Comment: Hmm, that seems like it should work. Are you sure you enabled the intents for the correct application, and did you save your code and restart the bot after enabling intents?

Comment: Saved the code, restarted the bot, enabled the Server Members Intents in the correct application and still sending nothing...